# SWFUpload prematurely closing the connection on upload (nginx 499)

Tags: flash, upload, nginx, swfupload

I'm using swfupload to upload files to nginx.  It works fine for me & 99% of our users.
For a couple of users, however, it fails somehow during upload.  It opens a connection, but seems to close it before it's complete - nginx reports a 499 status in its access log, which is NGX_HTTP_CLIENT_CLOSED_REQUEST.

I managed to get hold of one of those users to get some more information.  They're running Flash 10.0.42, on XP with Firefox 3.5.7.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any suggestions on fixing it / how I might investigate further?

-Jonathan

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a real error on the client side (maybe caused by a firewall or something) or a timeout that leads to a client-side reset of the connection. What kind of file sizes are we talking about? Do you know how large the files were that the user tried to upload?

Comment: Yeah, turned out to be a overzealous firewall & network config.  I never found what specifically they'd disabled, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

In case nothing specific comes up here, here is a list of things I would ask the users for whom it does not work out.

- What kind of Internet connection do you have? Are you behind a (company) firewall?
- What kind of file were you trying to upload (file type and size)? What medium was that file stored on? (To exclude read errors when uploading from CD for example)
- OS version, Browser version, Flash version, personal firewall and/or antivirus software installed (to check for patterns)
- Did it work on the 2nd attempt?

Answer (score 1):

The 499 error is occured when:

- User successfully sends all data (including uploading file) to server
- User cancels request before getting response (ie, by refreshing page, all current requests will be canceled)
- Server (nginx) gets request and **successfully** process it (save uploaded file). Underlining server returns 200 response.
- Nginx gets response from underlining server, but when wants to send response to client (for POST request), the client has closed the connection and gone! So server cannot pass response to client.

So the 499 error **is a successfull upload** from server's point of view! But becaue client does not received any response nginx marks it as a 499 error.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities,

- The user refreshed the page before the upload was complete.
- The user's internet connection cut-out or hiccuped during the upload.
- If you're using PHP ( im guessing ) check the following settings in your php.ini.

**max_execution_time**

If the script takes too long to execute, the server will stop it based on this setting.

**max_file_uploads**

If the user tries to upload more files than this setting at once, then that might be the cause.

**upload_max_filesize**

If any of the files are larger than this setting, the file wont be uploaded. This can be handled before it hits the server on the client side with:

Sorry, but without more specific information, I can't narrow it down any further.

If it's only affecting 1% of your users, that's acceptable in my opinion ;) Personally I wouldn't waste time fixing a bug for the 1% unless its the client.